# select2 field that depends on another field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to implement the code show in this tutorial:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-how-to#add-a-select2-field-that-depends-on-another-field

However, this line returns `null` value:

`$form = collect($request->input('form'))->pluck('value', 'name');`

I don't know if i should use `input('form')` here as it is taken from the documentation for version 3.4 Does someone know if it works in version 4.

CrudController:

```
// CRUD::field('sub_district_id')
//     ->type('select2')
//     ->label('Kecamatan')
//     ->entity('sub_district')
//     ->attribute('sub_district_name')
//     ->model('App\Models\SubDistrict')
//     ->wrapper(['class' => 'form-group col-md-6']);
CRUD::field('sub_district_id')
    ->type('relationship')
    ->label('Kecamatan')
    ->attribute('sub_district_name')
    ->include_all_form_fields(true)
    ->wrapper(['class' => 'form-group col-md-6']);
CRUD::field('village_id')
    ->type('select2_from_ajax')
    ->label('Desa/Kelurahan')
    ->entity('village')
    ->attribute('village_name')
    ->model("App\Models\Village")
    ->wrapper(['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'])
    ->data_source(url('api/village'))
    ->placeholder('Pilih Desa/Kelurahan')
    ->minimum_input_length(0)
    ->dependencies(['sub_district_id'])
    ->method('GET'); // optional - HTTP method to use for the AJAX call (GET, POST)
```

ApiController:

```
$search_term = $request->input('q');
$form = collect($request->input('form'))->pluck('value', 'name');
// dump($form);

$options = Village::query();

if (!$form['sub_district_id']) {
    return [];
}

// if a category has been selected, only show articles in that category
if ($form['sub_district_id']) {
    $options = $options->where('sub_district_id', $form['sub_district_id']);
}

if ($search_term) {
    $results = $options->where('village_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search_term . '%')->paginate(10);
} else {
    $results = $options->paginate(10);
}

return $options->paginate(10);
```

Comment: is `$request->input('form')` populated to begin with?

Comment: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/1484 at this PR, maybe that `$form` should be getting all value from the form but I got nothing, you could try this demo too https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/demo

Comment: How about if you pass `'include_all_form_fields' => true,` to the field in question?  `$request->input('form')` should then have all the values of all fields on that page.

Comment: @tabacitu, It still returns `#items: []`, I added the example of my code

Comment: after trying to add `'include_all_form_fields' => true,` to field `village_id`, it works and return all value from the forms, thanks @tabacitu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this line to `village`'s field

`->include_all_form_fields(true)`

and it will return all the value from the form

CrudController:

```
// ...
CRUD::field('village_id')
    ->type('select2_from_ajax')
    ->label('Desa/Kelurahan')
    ->entity('village')
    ->attribute('village_name')
    ->model("\App\Models\Village")
    ->wrapper(['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'])
    ->data_source(url('api/village'))
    ->placeholder('Pilih Desa/Kelurahan')
    ->minimum_input_length(0)
    ->dependencies(['sub_district_id'])
    ->include_all_form_fields(true)
    ->method('GET'); // optional - HTTP method to use for the AJAX call (GET, POST)
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$form = collect($request->all())->get('value', 'name');
```

Comment: anyway thx, but it didn't fix my problem, still not get the value from the form